# Binary Ones Complement Operator in Java

Tags: java, bitwise-operators

Why and how does
    System.out.println(~4);
gives output -5
and
    System.out.println(~0);
gives output -1 ?

Comment: Integers in java use two's completement, not one's complement, and the operator you are using is called bitwise negation, not "binary one complement"

Comment: @fge but it *is* called ones complement.

Comment: That's right @harold. Ones complement is the most common term, followed by "bitwise NOT". I've never heard the term "bitwise negation" before. Although I see that term is also legit, it's scarily close to "negation" which in fact is 2s complement, and not what the OP is asking about. I'd avoid using that term due to potential confusion.

Answer (score 11):

```
4 is  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000100

~4 is 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111011 = -5

0 is  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000

~0 is 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 = -1
```

Comment: Simplest answer ever found for complementing any operator!

Answer (score 1):

negation of a number reverses it's bits. But on putting -(negative) sign on number logically it becomes `1+(~x)`.

Since `-x = 1+(~x)`
thus `(~x) = -x -1`

Answer (score 0):

And if you are wondering why

```
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111011 = -5
```

you could read more about two's complement and negative numbers:

[two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)